# Flutter: How to get birthdate from google sign in firebase? (Android and iOS)

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-signin

I want to get birthdate from google sign in firebase but I cannot see any birthdate. The only information I can get is the displayname, email, number and etc. Can you help me? Thank you!

Here is my code for getting user information after logging in using google.

```
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
var googleIdToken;
FirebaseUser user;

Future<FirebaseUser> signInWithGoogle() async {

   final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
   final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

 final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken);

googleIdToken = googleSignInAuthentication.idToken;

final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
user = authResult.user;

AuthService().googleLogin(googleIdToken).then((val) {

  if (val.data['success']) {
     var token2 = val.data['token'];

     AuthService().getInfo(token2).then((val) async {         
       var store = val.data['user'];
      
       await UserSimplePreferences.setEmail(store['email']);
       await UserSimplePreferences.setFirstName(store['firstname']);
       await UserSimplePreferences.setLastName(store['lastname']);
       await UserSimplePreferences.setUsername(store['username']);

      showDialog(context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context){
            return  _SuucessLogin();
          });
      EasyLoading.dismiss();

     });
  } else {
    print('WRONG EMAIL/ PASS');
  }
});

assert(!user.isAnonymous);
assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
assert(currentUser.uid == user.uid);

return user;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Due to the data security compliances, Google doesn't provide the birthdate directly in the API response. What it does is, when user completes the google login initiated by your firebase app, it prompts user with popup to let user allow the permission to grant access on birthdate.

In your firebase google authentication configuration you will have to define the scopes as follows for birthdate.

```
signInOptions: [
  {
    provider: fb.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    scopes: [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
    ],
    customParameters: {
      prompt: "select_account"
    }
  },
```

follow the post here to know how to add the scope in the google signin provider https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin

Comment: What part of the code should I put that? I'm getting an error.

Comment: you need to change the GoogleSignIn() instance or wherever you have configured the auth provider in your code. Read this link for detail https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth_platform_interface/latest/firebase_auth_platform_interface/GoogleAuthProvider-class.html